# Does the radius of a curve change with change in the frame of reference

Tags: coordinate-systems, circular-motion

If a person observes a circle of radius r in a frame of reference $O_1$, does that radius change in a different frame of reference $O_2$. In general, does the radius of a curve change with change in the frame of reference?

Comment: If you accept special relativity as a consistent theory (which most of us do), then yes: length contraction. It is totally unclear what frames of reference you consider.

Comment: The frame of reference refers to inertial frame only and let's assume that the maximum speed in any of the frames as well as the speed of the frames w.r.t. each other is less than 50m/s.